# Listview - select mosti similar item to value

Tags: vb.net, listview, similarity

How would one select item in listview (first column) that is most similar to string value from e.g. label or textbox.

Listview is populated with this code :

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ListView1.Items.Clear()
    ListView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details
    ListView1.Columns.Add("COL1", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left) 'KONTO
    ListView1.Columns.Add("COL2", 140, HorizontalAlignment.Left) 'NAZIV

    Dim FilePath As String = "W:\GLAVNI\KOR14\"
    Dim DBF_File As String = "MATIKGL"
    Dim ColName As String = "KONTO"
    'Dim naz As String
    Using con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & FilePath & _
    " ;Extended Properties=dBASE IV")
        con.Open()
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM MATIKGL ORDER BY KONTO, NAZIV", con)
            Using reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                If reader.HasRows Then
                    While (reader.Read())
                        Me.ListView1.Items.Add(reader("KONTO"))
                        'ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Add(rdr.Item("YourColumnName").ToString)
                        'BELOW SELECTS ALL ITEMS THAT STARTS WITH 2020-
                        For i = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
                            If ListView1.Items(i).ToString.Contains("2020-") Then

                            Else
                                ListView1.Items.Remove(ListView1.Items(i))
                            End If
                        Next

                    End While

                Else

                End If
            End Using
        End Using
        con.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

I have one textbox and a button.
Textual input from textbox should be compared with all items in listview and closest should be selected. **One more thing : All items are sorted alphabetically**

Button code is :

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ListView1.MultiSelect = False
    ListView1.FullRowSelect = True

    Dim checkInt As Integer = FindItem(ListView1, "2020-" & TextBox1.Text)'this one is changed since all items starts with "2020-"& UCASE TEXT
    If checkInt <> -1 Then

        ListView1.Items(checkInt).Selected = True
        ListView1.Focus()

    Else
        Label1.Text = "Search string not found"
    End If
End Sub
```

**UPDATED CODE**

```
            Dim checkInt As Integer = FindItem(ListView1, "2020-" & TextBox3.Text)

        If checkInt <> -1 Then

            TextBox4.Focus()

        Else
            Label14.Text = "NEMA"
            On Error GoTo ext
            Dim li As ListViewItem
            ListView1.SelectedItems.Clear()
            ListView1.HideSelection = False

            li = ListView1.FindItemWithText("2020-" & UCase(TextBox3.Text))

            If Not (li Is Nothing) Then
                Me.ListView1.Focus()
                li.Selected = True
                li.EnsureVisible()
            ElseIf li Is Nothing Then
                li = ListView1.FindItemWithText("2020-" & Strings.Left(TextBox3.Text, 1))
                Me.ListView1.Focus()
                li.Selected = True
                li.EnsureVisible()
            Else

            End If

            Exit Sub
ext:

            TextBox3.Text = ""
            TextBox3.Focus()
            Label14.Text = "String not found"



        End If
```

This one works.

I know it's not the best solution but it's working. 
Could fixed this without your help, thank you Phillip Trelford

Comment: What's your definition of similarity? Have you tried `string.Contains()`? Or Regex?

Comment: Would you be so kind to help me with those functions (I've never use them). Let's say that there are three values in listview : "Alpha", "Apple" and "Ask" if I would enter "Ann" I would like for Apple to be selected, and if e.g."Arm" is entered "Apple" would be selected.

If first letter is found, second is searched for and so on, when letter not found select closest value based on that pattern.

Comment: If you have a clear idea of what you mean by "similar", you could write an algorith giving each item a score from 0 (exact match) and going up, and returning the lowest score. One does not simply get into regex.

Comment: I know how to do that in Excel with VLOOKUP function but can not do that in VB. ...closest in string terms (alphabet)

Answer (score 3):

Define a function to score two strings for closeness then use LINQ to find the lowest score, i.,e.

```
' Example score function
Function Score(a As String, b As String) As Integer
    Dim index = 0
    While index < a.Length And index < b.Length
        Dim diff = Math.Abs(AscW(a(index)) - AscW(b(index)))
        If diff <> 0 Then Return diff
        index += 1
    End While
    Return Math.Abs(a.Length - b.Length)
End Function

Function Closest(searchWord As String, words As String()) As String
    Dim ordered =
        From w In words
        Select Word = w, Score = Score(w, searchWord)
        Order By Score

    Return ordered.First().Word
End Function

Sub Main()
    Dim words = {"Alpha", "Apple", "Ask"}
    Dim searchWord = "Ann"
    Dim word = Closest(searchWord, words)
    Console.WriteLine(word)
End Sub
```

**Update**

To select the value in a WinForms ListView, you need to do roughly this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
ListView1.MultiSelect = False
ListView1.FullRowSelect = True

Dim prefix = "2020-"
' Extract items from Listview
Dim items = New List(Of String)()
For Each item In ListView1.Items
    items.Add(item)
Next
Dim words = items.ToArray()
Dim searchWord = TextBox1.Text
Dim resultWord = Closest(searchWord, words)
'this one is changed since all items starts with "2020-"& UCASE TEXT
Dim checkInt As Integer = FindItem(ListView1, prefix & resultWord) 
If checkInt <> -1 Then

    ListView1.Items(checkInt).Selected = True
    ListView1.Focus()

Else
    Label1.Text = "Search string not found"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I apply to listview1? I know how to apply it for textbox `Dim searchWord = UCase(TextBox1.Text)`... This line should be changed to point to listview1 column, but I don't know how `Dim words = {"Alpha", "Apple", "Ask"}`

Comment: @JovicaBozic You should be able to use the words from the collection you used to assign to ListView.Items otherwise read from that value. To select the word in the ListView use SelectedItems (WinForms) or SelectedValue (WPF).

Comment: Then I have "value of type - can not be converted for 1-dimensional array of string" error/correction for `words` in this line `Dim word = Closest(searchWord, words)`

Comment: @JovicaBozic if you're pulling the words from ListView.Items you may need to convert to a string array, i.e. ListView.Items.Select(Function(w) w.ToString()).ToArray(). Sorry without having a copy of your source it's a little hard for me to give you an exact solution.

Comment: I've put the code above and I am hope I'm not confusing.

Comment: I get three errors in button click event : ")" in `(prefix.Length)` if ")" added then error : "Select is not a member of ...listviewcollection"; words is not declared and last error is syntax error in `).ToArray()`

Comment: What I was trying to do there is extract the strings from the ListView .Items collection. The error may occur if you haven't imported System.Linq or the Items collection doesn't support LINQ. Instead of pushing the words directly to the ListView.Items collection, you could collect them in an array as a member variable  and pass that. Or you can use a for each loop on ListView.Items instead of the .Select and collect them into a List(of String).

Comment: Could you please simplify that, I am using (trying to) VB for a month so your last post it's to complicated for me to understand?

Comment: Or can you please show me how to find first item in listview that starts with specific letter, if `strings.left(textbox1.text,1) = "F"`, select first item starting with letter "F"?

Comment: I've added a for loop to the example to extract the items from the ListView.Items

Comment: Now I have an error in `items.Add(item)` : Conversion from type 'ListViewItem' to type 'String' is not valid.

If I change that line to : `items.Add(TextBox1.Text.ToString)` selection works but only when exact item name is put in textbox, otherwise I get Search string not found. Doesn't work with partial input.

Comment: @JovicaBozic good work, that sounds like progress at least. I'd recommend using the debugger to see what is happening now. If you are calling Closest and using the returned value it should always give you a match.

Comment: Closest value doesn't work ("Search string not found"), I have to input exact value to get a selection. Since I don't know values of all items in listview, I have to use partial match (from textbox) to select some value close to value I am looking for in listview, and I don't know how to adapt code for that.

Comment: There is also `ListView1.FindNearestItem` but I can not find anything that I can adapt to my problem.

Comment: @JovicaBozic sorry just re-read your earlier comment, where you do `items.Add(TextBox1.Text.ToString)` you are making all the items the search term. You need to add the items. Try `items.Add(item.ToString)` instead.

Comment: I've updated code in original post, it's working for now. Thank you so much.